# Implementing Generic Trait for Enum in Rust

Tags: generics, rust, enums, traits

Is there a way to implement a Trait with a generic type T for an enum? something like this:

```rust
use rand::thread_rng;
use rand::seq::SliceRandom;

pub enum Color {
    Red,
    Blue,
    Green,
}

trait Shuffable {
    fn values<T>() -> Vec<T>;

    fn shuffled<T: Shuffable>() -> Vec<T> {
        let mut items = T::values();
        items.shuffle(&mut thread_rng());

        items
    }
}

impl Shuffable for Color {
    fn values<Color>() -> Vec<Color> {
        vec![Color::Red, Color::Blue, Color::Green]
    }
}
```

This errors on not being able to relate Enum items to the Type itself

```rust
error[E0599]: no associated item named `Red` found for type parameter `Color` in the current scope
  --> src/game.rs:25:21
   |
25 |         vec![Color::Red, Color::Blue, Color::Green]
   |                     ^^^ associated item not found in `Color`

error[E0599]: no associated item named `Blue` found for type parameter `Color` in the current scope
  --> src/game.rs:25:33
   |
25 |         vec![Color::Red, Color::Blue, Color::Green]
   |                                 ^^^^ associated item not found in `Color`

error[E0599]: no associated item named `Green` found for type parameter `Color` in the current scope
  --> src/game.rs:25:46
   |
25 |         vec![Color::Red, Color::Blue, Color::Green]
   |                                              ^^^^^ associated item not found in `Color`
```

I have checked https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/52118 but it doesn't seem to be related!

Comment: At a high level, I think I understand what you are trying to achieve, but how do imagine the calling code would look like? How would the trait `Shuffable` be used from a main function?

Comment: So, the code I'm creating has a lot of Enums that should have a function to return the "values" of the Ver<Enum> shuffled, the trait is to avoid writing the same code over and over for each enum... :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a starting point, we can make your code work as follows:

```rust
use rand::thread_rng;
use rand::seq::SliceRandom;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum Color {
    Red,
    Blue,
    Green,
}

trait Shuffable where Self: Sized {
    fn values() -> Vec<Self>;
    fn shuffled() -> Vec<Self> {
        let mut items = Self::values();
        items.shuffle(&mut thread_rng());
        items
    }
}

impl Shuffable for Color {
    fn values() -> Vec<Self> {
        vec![Color::Red, Color::Blue, Color::Green]
    }   
}

fn main() {
    let shuffled = Color::shuffled();
    println!("{:?}", shuffled)
}
```

`Self` has to be sized since the concrete type that is implementing `Shuffable` needs to be stored inside a vector and we need to know how much space we are allocating.

I think the point of confusion may be with the generic parameter `T`, I assume you were thinking that this is for representing the `Color` type? If so, this is not necessary since the type for which you are implementing the trait is represented through `Self`. `T` introduces another type which is not constrained anywhere.